# Understand SolrInputDocument's addField method with boost value

Tags: solr

I am still new to solr (i feel silly to ask simple questions, blush), but what are the differences between the two methods below? which one should i use? what if i set the boost value to 1.0f for all of the fields in a document?

1. add field without boost

   public void addField(String name, Object value)
   Add a field with implied null value for boost.
2. add field with boost value

   public void addField(String name,
               Object value,
               float boost)
   Adds a field with the given name, value and boost. If a field with the name already exists, then it is updated to the new value and boost.

Thanks a lot for your help :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read Solr's wiki (or my book, chapter 5) about what a "boost" or what "boosting" is.  In a nutshell, index time boosting offers the opportunity to increase the score of a document that is matched via a query matching the specified field.  It's a multiplier, and so the default is in effect 1.0.  Most apps should eschew index-time boosting for more-flexible query-time boosting.  For example, use the dismax parser's "qf" param.